# Creating a text highlight in the background using javascript at give start and end indexes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I found difficulties while highlighting text in one div by using their list indexes

For instance, I have text div similar to below:

```
<div> <!--Highlight at given index in this div -->
   <p>As a friend of Romeo’s, Mercutio supports the Montague’s in the ancient feud. An example of Mercutio defending the Montague’s is when Tybalt, a member of the loathed Capulet family, abuses Romeo and Mercutio intervenes on Romeo’s behalf. Attempting to restore peace, Romeo gets between the two combatants and Mercutio “hath got his mortal hurt” (Page 149; Act 3, Scene 1) on Romeo’s account. In spite of his “life shall pay the forfeit of peace” (page 17; Act 1, Scene 1), Romeo seeks revenge on Tybalt as he loves his murdered friend. As Romeo kills Tybalt out of love for Mercutio, Shakespeare suggests that love conquered the thought of being penalized with death.</p>
   <p>Want to  overlap this highlight too</p>
   <p>Want to  overlap this highlight too</p>
</div>
```

HTML escaped version would be  like below:

```
As a friend of Romeo’s, Mercutio supports the Montague’s in the ancient feud. An example of Mercutio defending the Montague’s is when Tybalt, a member of the loathed Capulet family, abuses Romeo and Mercutio intervenes on Romeo’s behalf. Attempting to restore peace, Romeo gets between the two combatants and Mercutio “hath got his mortal hurt” (Page 149; Act 3, Scene 1) on Romeo’s account. In spite of his “life shall pay the forfeit of peace” (page 17; Act 1, Scene 1), Romeo seeks revenge on Tybalt as he loves his murdered friend. As Romeo kills Tybalt out of love for Mercutio, Shakespeare suggests that love conquered the thought of being penalized with death.
Want to  overlap this highlight too
Want to  overlap this highlight too
```

I have one list of highlight will be something like below:

```
[
  {
    "id": "cb8c8875-fba4-4abd-9cca-9cc304b9cba6",
    "start_index": 179,
    "end_index": 184,
    "color": "green",
  },
  {
    "id": "9698dd27-ed20-4824-82b0-1548016b5839",
    "start_index": 6,
    "end_index": 53,
    "color": "yellow",
]
```

### *What I tried:*

I wondered that Javascript *Range* object is used for making range from given indexes. This would return a range it can be used to get Bounding rectangle(s). But did not get that how to Make that *Range* object from indexes.

I want a javascript code to add absolute positioned highlight div at given text indexes (*start_index* and *end_index*) as explained in below-attached images.

Please find sample output below.

[image: Highlight ouput]

Any help would be appreciated.

If required more information on the same, then leave a comment.

### **Note and update** :

- Use `getBoundingClientRect` or `getClientRects()` for getting absolute position
- The text in div is not static it may vary.
- Iterate through the highlights and create span with the characters using start and end indexes and add suitable classNames to those span based on color
- div may contain italic and bold texts

Comment: is `<p>` have the same `id` as in the list? how does the communication between the array and the HTML goes?

Comment: No the id in the list is used for just event and `onclick` highlight process

Comment: A mere “I want” is not an appropriate way to ask here. This is not a code-writing service, you need to come up with your own approach. We can try and help you _fix_ your approach, if you can not get it fully working on your own. But _you_ still need to show some initial effort here first of all.

Comment: Actually  I did some effort if I write it here the question would be awful So that I kept it as minimal as possible. Thanks for your suggestion. I am updating this Question accordingly.

Comment: Are you creating the html dynamically? or your html is rigid. I mean it's structure cannot be changed?

Comment: Thanks for asking, The text is not rigid/static it may vary and the highlight list is also variable. I've updated the question

Comment: I can give you idea how you can approach this. iterate through the highlights and create span with the characters using start and end indexes and add suitable classNames to those span based on color.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @chandan_kr_jha I already tried that way. When the text in bold or italic in the HTML that it would cause conflicts. Updating the question

Comment: Yeah. Then you have to do it the hard way of identifying the tags of bold and italic and add spans before and after as well. Will be a complex logic.

Answer (score 1):

### Disclaimer:

We implemented text highlighting in cross-platform document-viewer react app, where user can add highlights by touch and we load them the next time they look at a document. Needless to say, it's super complicated.

The most difficult problem is getting a text position from rendered text. I assume that you do not have to do handle that part too, or the answer might become very long.
Three lead developers invested quite few days into getting a working solution, so be warned.

It's important to realize that text positions in source code (e.g. the HTML text in your DB), rendered (browser's `node.innerHTML`) and visible text **are different**.

The browser even inserts virtual nodes in some cases. If you need to convert from one to the other, you first have to normalize the positions, e.g. by walking through the content of `node.innerHTML` and ignore tags, multiple spaces and newlines.

### Solution:

Placing boxes above the text is hard to implement (cross-browser) and does not play well with multi-line text or resizing of content areas.

On the other hand, inserting tags into the text does not work straigt away when the highlight starts in one tag context and ends in another, e.g. when you have sub-tags like `<p>Hello <b>World Wide Web</b></p>` and you want to highlight "Hello World".

The trick is to insert empty-bodied marker tags at start and end location first and add the highlights in a second step. When you do so, it is important to walk backwards through the content, since inserting changes positions.

**Step 1**

`sourceContent` in the code below can be `parentNode.innerHTML`, but if you have to use that, the positions will likely be offset due to HTML tags, spaces and newlines. So if you have the source content (e.g. from a DB), use it!

```
insertHighlightMarkerTags(sourceContent = '', highlights = []) {
    const arrSortByIdx = [];

    // collect marker locations for start and end of highlights
    highlights.forEach((record) => {
        arrSortByIdx.push({
            start: true,
            idx: record.startIndex,
            record,
        });

        arrSortByIdx.push({
            end: true,
            idx: record.endIndex,
            record,
        });
    });

    let processedContent = sourceContent;

    // sort marker location in reverse order, so we can insert them without messing with the index positions
    arrSortByIdx.sort((a, b) => b.idx - a.idx);

    // insert marker locations in reverse order
    arrSortByIdx.forEach((item) => {
        const tagName = item.start ? 'mon' : 'moff';
        const tag = `<${tagName} data-id="${item.record.id}"></${tagName}>`;
        processedContent = processedContent.slice(0, item.idx) + tag + processedContent.slice(item.idx);
    });

    return processedContent;
},
```

**Step 2**

We now have the locations as tags inside our content. They only serve as markers and won't be displayed. But they allows us to create a [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) by querying them:

```
getRangeFor(domNode, record) {
    const range = document.createRange();

    const fromElem = domNode.querySelector(`mon[data-id="${record.id}"]`);
    const toElem = domNode.querySelector(`moff[data-id="${record.id}"]`);
    if (fromElem === null || toElem === null) {
        // preselect the whole page and then reduce the selection, if necessary
        range.selectNodeContents(domNode);
    }

    if (fromElem) {
        range.setStartAfter(fromElem);
    }

    if (toElem) {
        range.setEndBefore(toElem);
    }
    return range;
}
```

**Step 3**

Wrapping text into marker tags can now be achieved with the awesome [wrap-range-text](https://github.com/lakenen/wrap-range-text) library. (There are many similar libraries, but most won't work cross-browser, thanks to weird bugs in Edge and IE):

```
import wrapRange from 'wrap-range-text';

createMarker(range, highlight, start = false) {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('mark');
    wrapper.setAttribute('style', `background-color: ${highlight.color}`);
    wrapper.setAttribute('data-id', record.id);
    wrapper.setAttribute('class', className);
    wrapRange(wrapper, range);
},
```

Comment: I see, That's an interesting solution to pass empty mark tags and then use range wrapper. Lemme check it out. Thank you so much for the descriptive answer @dube Its so clear and informative.

Comment: You are welcome. If you ever have to figure out text positions in rendered text, create a new question and mark me. As I mentioned above, it's the most annoying/complicated part and I didn't want to extend the answer here even more :)

Comment: PS: The insertion logic above even works for overlapping highlights. Adding opacity to the background and make them overlap is quite fun